# Bash Scripting- Switches

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "p:" opt; do
case ${opt} in
 p )#print the argument value
echo "I like $OPTARG programming"
;;
 \? )
```

What if i want to print an error  if I don't give '-p'

Comment: Even though it does not answer the question, have a look at [BashFAQ35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) about the usefulness of `getopts`.

Comment: To answer your question, just use a variable to check if you used the option or not. After the while loop you can validate if you used the option, if not print the error.

Comment: The general flow with `getopts` is: 1) set default variable values, 2) process options (with `getopts`) & set/change variables, 3) check values & throw any relevant errors, and 4) act on the values in the variables.

Answer (score 2):

When I have a required option in my shell scripts, I use parameter expansion, specifically: `${variable:?message}`, which will print `message` if `$variable` is empty or unset. You can introduce this into your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "p:" opt
do
  case ${opt} in
    p) valueToPrint=$OPTARG ;;
  esac
done

# print the argument value
printf "I like %s programming\n" ${valueToPrint:?A -p option is required.}
```

You have effectively three scenarios that could arise with this program:

- Without the parameter:

  ```
  $ bash test.sh
  test.sh: line 10: valueToPrint: A -p option is required.
  ```
- With the option flag but no parameter:

  ```
  $ bash test.sh -p
  test.sh: option requires an argument -- p
  test.sh: line 10: valueToPrint: A -p option is required.
  ```
- With both the option flag and the parameter:

  ```
  $ bash test.sh -p bash
  I like bash programming
  ```